# Google Analytics API - Account not verified?

Tags: google-analytics, account, verify

I'm installing a script for web trading which allow users to connect their own google analytics account to show real analytics.

This script ask me for GA Client ID, Client Secret and Developer Key, so I fill these details and I try to connect a Google Analytic account as normal user, then I got the error: "Your Google Analytics account has not verified."

I'm not sure if it's GA dev account related or about the user account.

I have been looking for the Google Documentation to see how to verify it but no luck.

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/63950?hl=en

> If you're not sure whether your account is verified, you can find out
>   by signing in to My Account. You'll see a message asking you to verify
>   your account if it has not yet been verified.

Then I go to My Account but there is no message asking me to verify my account, neither dev nor user account.